# How to get devanagari numerals in latex or xetex

Tags: xetex, unicode, indic

How to get devanagari numerals in `xetex` or `latex` - especially in enumerate environment?

I can use unicode to write devanagari text but I am unable to get devenagari numerals in section numbers, enumerate environment, etc.

Here is the basic code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Heading}

देवनागरी

Same English Text

१ २ ३ ४ ५ ६ ७ ८ ९ ०

\begin{enumerate}
    \item   This is first
    \item   देवनागरी
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above document compiled with xetex]

And I am compiling using xetex (default set-up on Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You'll probably need a specific font for that. SIL has some devanagari fonts: http://www.sil.org/sil/news/2011/annapurna-font.htm

Comment: I can see devanagari numerals and devanagari text (१, २, देवनागरी, etc.) But the numbers in section numbers, enumerate environment are still arabic

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's currently no interface for changing all numerals to Devanagari ones. However you can define your own:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}

\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

% renew all representation of counters
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\devanagarinumeral{section}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\devanagarinumeral{page}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\devanagarinumeral{enumi}}

\begin{document}

\section{\foreignlanguage{english}{Section Heading}}

देवनागरी

\foreignlanguage{english}{Some English Text}

१ २ ३ ४ ५ ६ ७ ८ ९ ०

\begin{enumerate}
    \item   \foreignlanguage{english}{This is first}
    \item   देवनागरी
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

A more risky approach is to change the meaning of `\@arabic` (the internal command that represents counter with arabic digits):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@arabic#1{\expandafter\devanagaridigits\expandafter{\number#1}}
\makeatother
```

This would spare you from redefining all needed counter representations, but may break packages that rely on `\@arabic`.

[image]

Comment: I tried both the approaches. It produces an error `! Undefined control sequence.
\devanagarinumeral #1->\devanagaridigits 
                                         {\number \csname c@#1\endcsname }
l.20 ...foreignlanguage{english}{Section Heading}}
`

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{devanagaridigits}`; on my machine this package is automatically loaded, perhaps your TeX distribution is older than mine.

Comment: This has opened up Pandora's Box! My texlive installation is from Ubuntu repositories. It is a 2009 version. I could not find any devanagaridigits package in the repositories or on ctan.org

Should I, therefore, go and install latest tex-live 2012? Can I install and use it where I do not have root access?

I know, this should be a separate question. But thought might ask here for a link to these answers.

Thanks, @egreg

Comment: @deshmukh As far as I know TeX Live 2012 is in the Debian "testing" tree, but installing it requires root access anyway.

Comment: thanks @egreg. I have accepted your answer and passed on the bounty. Will look up on installing Tex Live 2012 (with/ without root access). :)

Comment: All goes well ... except subsection numbering. A subsection is still numbered as १.1! I tried adding a \renewcommand{\thesubsection} but no use. Any solution there??

Comment: @deshmukh `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\devanagarinumeral{subsection}}` should do.

Comment: Thanks! It did work perfectly. I was only replacing section with subsection in the \renewcommand. Guess that was the wrong bit

Answer (score 4):

There is such a mapping, use Mapping=devanagarinumerals as the font feature. This mapping exists since July 2007, originally distributed with the velthuis package, now it is included in xetex-devanagari.

Comment: Where exactly does one set this mapping up? Will be useful if you can give a MWE/ the exact command.

Comment: Using polyglossia and fontspec: `\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Chandas}`