# Page numbering in ToC in a different language/script

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex, page-numbering, kannada

I am typesetting a book in Kannada language and everything is working fine.

The book contains many chapters and a couple of front matter files. As is the practice, I have set the page numbering to roman for the front matter and arabic for the main matter. The arabic page numbering is rendered to Kannada digits and the output is as expected. But, the page numbering in `toc` for the front matter also comes out in Kannada digits rather than English.

The `contentsname` re-defining also is not working.

Here is the `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{kannada}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Kannada}
\newfontfamily{\english}{Noto Sans}

\newcommand{\kannadanumeral}[1]{%
  \kannadadigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\kannadanumeral{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\kannadanumeral{page}}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ಪರಿವಿಡಿ}   % this is not working

% We will define some fancy page styles here
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}          % Empty every style
  \fancyhead[LO, LE]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\rfoot{\english\roman{page}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \rfoot{\english\roman{page}}
}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{ಮುನ್ನುಡಿ}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ಮುನ್ನುಡಿ}

ಕರ್ನಾಟಕ ನಾಡು ಮತ್ತು ಆ ನಾಡಿನ ಜನ ಹಾಗೂ ಅವರಾಡುವ ಭಾಷೆ. 

\chapter{ಇತಿಹಾಸ}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\rfoot{\kannadanumeral{page}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{}      % clear all header fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \rfoot{{\kannadanumeral{page}}}
}

ಅಶೋಕನ ಬ್ರಾಹ್ಮೀ ಲಿಪಿ ಉತ್ತರಕ್ಕೆ ಕಾಲಸಿ ಮತ್ತು ಭಾರತ-ನೇಪಾಲ ಗಡಿಯಲ್ಲಿರುವ ರುಮ್ಮಿಂದೈಯಿಂದ ದಕ್ಷಿಣಕ್ಕೆ ಮೈಸೂರುವರೆಗೂ ಪೂರ್ವಕ್ಕೆ ಒರಿಸ್ಸದಿಂದ ಪಶ್ಚಿಮಕ್ಕೆ ಜುನಾಗಢ ಮತ್ತು ಮುಂಬಯಿವರೆಗೂ ದೊರೆತ ಅಶೋಕ ಸಾಮ್ರಾಟನ ಧರ್ಮಶಾಸನಗಳಲ್ಲಿ ಕಂಡುಬರುತ್ತದೆ. ಈ ಲಿಪಿಯು ಅಶೋಕನ ಕಾಲದಲ್ಲಿ ಪ್ರಚಲಿತವಿದ್ದ ಪಾಕೃತ ಬಾಷೆಯಾಗಿ ಉಪಯೋಗಿಸಲ್ಪಟ್ಟಿದೆ.

{\english This is some text in English.}

\chapter{ಪರಿಣಾಮ}

ಕನ್ನಡ ಲಿಪಿಯ ಒಂದು ವೈಶಿಷ್ಟ್ಯವೆಂದರೆ ಪ್ರಾಚೀನಕಾಲದಿಂದಲೂ ಕಾಗುಣಿತಾಕ್ಷರದ ಹೃಸ್ವ ಮತ್ತು ದೀರ್ಘ ಎ ಮತ್ತು ಏ ಕಾರಗಳನ್ನು ಹಾಗೂ ಒ ಮತ್ತು ಓ ಕಾರಗಳನ್ನು ಒಂದೇ ಸಂಜ್ಞೆಯಿಂದ ಸೂಚಿಸುತ್ತಿದ್ದು ಅವುಗಳಲ್ಲಿಯ ಹೃಸ್ವ ಮತ್ತು ದೀರ್ಘ ವರ್ಣಗಳ ಭೇದವನ್ನು ಸಂದರ್ಭಾನುಸಾರವಾಗಿ ತಿಳಿದುಕೊಳ್ಳಬೇಕಾಗಿತ್ತು.

\chapter{ಕನ್ನಡದ ಶುದ್ಧಾಕ್ಷರಗಳ ವಿಧಗಳು}

ಕೇಶಿರಾಜನ ಪ್ರಕಾರ ಕನ್ನಡ ಶುದ್ಧಗೆಯಲ್ಲಿ ಐದು ವಿಧಗಳು. ಅವುಗಳು ಕ್ರಮವಾಗಿ : ಸ್ವರ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ವರ್ಗೀಯ ವ್ಯಂಜನ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ಅವರ್ಗೀಯ ವ್ಯಂಜನ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ಯೋಗವಾಹ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ದೇಶಿಯ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು. ಆದರೆ ಕನ್ನಡ ಪಠ್ಯಾನುಸಾರ ಪ್ರಾಥಮಿಕ ಮತ್ತು ಮಾಧ್ಯಮಿಕ ತರಗತಿಯ ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಗಳು ಒಟ್ಟು ಕನ್ನಡ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳನ್ನು ಈ ಕೆಳಗಿನಂತೆ ಗ್ರಹಿಸಿಕೊಂಡಿದ್ದಾರೆ. 

\end{document}
```

I am attaching the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

How do I get the page numbers correctly in the toc? Also, how to change `contentsname`?

Comment: Use `\frontmatter` for the front matter, then `\mainmatter` for the main stuff and `\endmatter` if you have things like appendices or an index at the end.

Comment: Try putting `\renewcommand...` for the TOC name after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: For the numbering to work properly, I think you need a customised page numbering scheme or else you have to manage everything yourself.

Comment: @cfr, `contentsname` now is set after moving it as you suggested. Using `\fronmatter` makes the page number in `toc` appear as `iii`rather than `೩`. But, it renders as boxes because the font lacks those characters (i think). How to customise the numbering scheme?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82990/xelatex-devanagari-page-numbers-in-tableofcontents help? Or the linked question?

Comment: If you look at my code, I got ideas from there :-)

Comment: Then you should have attributed it, partly for licence reasons, but mostly because it makes it easier for people to help you. And I *have* looked at your code. But it's not obvious you've seen that and not something similar or that you've not just come up with something similar.

Comment: It's extremely annoying to get a comment such as 'If you look at my code ...' when you've just spent a bunch of time doing nothing but looking at your code in order to help you.

Comment: Sorry that my comment annoyed you. Since you took the trouble of commenting, I knew you had already seen that. My English language skills need working.

Comment: No problem. I'm sorry if I misinterpreted your intent. I was tired and didn't realise English wasn't your first language or I'd not have reacted that way. And, to be honest, I overreacted anyway. Nuances just get lost online and it's far too easy to take offence when stuff is just written with no hint of intent. I'm sorry I got annoyed and I'm sorry I told you that. I should know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a result of reading `polyglossia`'s documentation, so I recommend that. My guiding idea was to use the apparatus provided by LaTeX and `polyglossia` insofar as that's possible and the intervene manually only when I could find no way to avoid it.

To do this, you need to set up your language configuration properly. This means English should be an 'other' language and you should specify such things as `Script` when specifying fonts. I suspect `Kannada` maybe the default, but there is also `Kannada v.2` and it seemed easier to just specify it.

Then you have access to things such as `\localnumeral*{<counter>}`. You don't want to define `\thepage` this way in the preamble, however, because you want roman numerals in the first part of the document. So set up the numbering for that and switch to Kannada afterwards. This means you only need one `plain` definition and the correct things get written to the `.toc`.

You also need to move the redefinition of the contents name after `\begin{document}` and `polyglossia` recommends configuring languages only after all packages are loaded. (This is in contrast with `babel`, where it's usually good to do this as soon as you can.)

```
\documentclass{book}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699800/ i gwestiwn mas: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699797/    
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% polyglossia says configure languages after all package loaded
\setdefaultlanguage{kannada}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}% or american or whatever
\setmainfont[Script=Kannada]{Noto Sans Kannada}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Noto Sans}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\localnumeral*{chapter}}

% We will define some fancy page styles here
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}          % Empty every style
\fancyhead[LO, LE]{\leftmark}
  
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \rfoot{\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ಪರಿವಿಡಿ}   % this is not working
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand* \thepage  {\textenglish{\roman{page}}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{ಮುನ್ನುಡಿ}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ಮುನ್ನುಡಿ}

ಕರ್ನಾಟಕ ನಾಡು ಮತ್ತು ಆ ನಾಡಿನ ಜನ ಹಾಗೂ ಅವರಾಡುವ ಭಾಷೆ. 

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand* \thepage {\localnumeral*{page}}

\chapter{ಇತಿಹಾಸ}


ಅಶೋಕನ ಬ್ರಾಹ್ಮೀ ಲಿಪಿ ಉತ್ತರಕ್ಕೆ ಕಾಲಸಿ ಮತ್ತು ಭಾರತ-ನೇಪಾಲ ಗಡಿಯಲ್ಲಿರುವ ರುಮ್ಮಿಂದೈಯಿಂದ ದಕ್ಷಿಣಕ್ಕೆ ಮೈಸೂರುವರೆಗೂ ಪೂರ್ವಕ್ಕೆ ಒರಿಸ್ಸದಿಂದ ಪಶ್ಚಿಮಕ್ಕೆ ಜುನಾಗಢ ಮತ್ತು ಮುಂಬಯಿವರೆಗೂ ದೊರೆತ ಅಶೋಕ ಸಾಮ್ರಾಟನ ಧರ್ಮಶಾಸನಗಳಲ್ಲಿ ಕಂಡುಬರುತ್ತದೆ. ಈ ಲಿಪಿಯು ಅಶೋಕನ ಕಾಲದಲ್ಲಿ ಪ್ರಚಲಿತವಿದ್ದ ಪಾಕೃತ ಬಾಷೆಯಾಗಿ ಉಪಯೋಗಿಸಲ್ಪಟ್ಟಿದೆ.

\textenglish{This is some text in English.}

\chapter{ಪರಿಣಾಮ}

ಕನ್ನಡ ಲಿಪಿಯ ಒಂದು ವೈಶಿಷ್ಟ್ಯವೆಂದರೆ ಪ್ರಾಚೀನಕಾಲದಿಂದಲೂ ಕಾಗುಣಿತಾಕ್ಷರದ ಹೃಸ್ವ ಮತ್ತು ದೀರ್ಘ ಎ ಮತ್ತು ಏ ಕಾರಗಳನ್ನು ಹಾಗೂ ಒ ಮತ್ತು ಓ ಕಾರಗಳನ್ನು ಒಂದೇ ಸಂಜ್ಞೆಯಿಂದ ಸೂಚಿಸುತ್ತಿದ್ದು ಅವುಗಳಲ್ಲಿಯ ಹೃಸ್ವ ಮತ್ತು ದೀರ್ಘ ವರ್ಣಗಳ ಭೇದವನ್ನು ಸಂದರ್ಭಾನುಸಾರವಾಗಿ ತಿಳಿದುಕೊಳ್ಳಬೇಕಾಗಿತ್ತು.

\chapter{ಕನ್ನಡದ ಶುದ್ಧಾಕ್ಷರಗಳ ವಿಧಗಳು}

ಕೇಶಿರಾಜನ ಪ್ರಕಾರ ಕನ್ನಡ ಶುದ್ಧಗೆಯಲ್ಲಿ ಐದು ವಿಧಗಳು. ಅವುಗಳು ಕ್ರಮವಾಗಿ : ಸ್ವರ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ವರ್ಗೀಯ ವ್ಯಂಜನ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ಅವರ್ಗೀಯ ವ್ಯಂಜನ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ಯೋಗವಾಹ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು, ದೇಶಿಯ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳು. ಆದರೆ ಕನ್ನಡ ಪಠ್ಯಾನುಸಾರ ಪ್ರಾಥಮಿಕ ಮತ್ತು ಮಾಧ್ಯಮಿಕ ತರಗತಿಯ ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಗಳು ಒಟ್ಟು ಕನ್ನಡ ಅಕ್ಷರಗಳನ್ನು ಈ ಕೆಳಗಿನಂತೆ ಗ್ರಹಿಸಿಕೊಂಡಿದ್ದಾರೆ. 

\end{document}
```

[image: contents page with roman and Kannada numerals]

[image: chapter title in main document with localised numbering]

Comment: It works. Many thanks for the solution.

Comment: @mas I'm glad it helped. I suspect there may be things I haven't thought of, though, because I don't usually use `polyglossia`.