# How to Type Bengali Script in Latex?

Tags: fonts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%
% This file is a sample tex file to illustrate use of
% XeTeX in typesetting Bengali document.
% License: GNU FDL: (C) Golam Mortuza Hossain, 2008
%
%
% Define fonts that you want to use
%
\font\serif="FreeSerif:script=beng"
\font\serifbb="FreeSerif:script=beng" at 24pt
\font\deffont="FreeSerif:script=beng" at 14pt
\font\mukti="Mukti Narrow Bold:script=beng"

%
% "script=beng" in above lines ensures that appropriate
% complex text rendering engines are used for proper
% rendering of Bengali.
%

\title{\bf\serifbb পাগলা দাশু}
\author{\bf\serif সুকুমার রায়}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\deffont %Default font used for the document
\maketitle

আমাদের স্কুলের যত ছাত্র তাহার মধ্যে এমন কেহই ছিল না, যে পাগলা দাশুকে
না চিনে। যে লোক আর কাহাকেও জানে না, সেও সকলের আগে পাগলা দাশুকে চিনিয়া
লয়। সেবার একজন নূতন দারোয়ান আসিল, একেবারে আনকোরা পাড়াগেঁয়ে লোক, কিন্তু
প্রথম যখন সে পাগলা দাশুর নাম শুনিল, তখনই সে আন্দাজে ঠিক ধরিয়া লইল যে,
এই ব্যক্তিই পাগলা দাশু। কারণ তার মুখের চেহারায়, কথাবার্তায়, চলনে চালনে
বোঝা যাইত যে তাহার মাথায় একটু 'ছিট' আছে। তাহার চোখদুটি গোল-গোল,
কানদুটা অনাবশ্যক রকমের বড়, মাথায় এক বস্তা ঝাঁকড়া চুল। চেহারাটা দেখিলেই
মনে হয়---

\vskip 10mm

% Specific font can be used for any part of the document
{\mukti বিঃদ্রঃ এই বাংলা পাতাটি লেখার জন্য XeTeX ব্যবহার করা হয়েছে।}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: How is this different from the other question you asked? [How to write Bengali in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99606/2693). There I suggested using the `polyglossia` package, which handles most of this for you.

Comment: When I run this TeX  in Kile,shows an error as follows : ' ./My_file.tex:13:Font\serif=FreeSerif:script=beng not lodable: Metric (TFM) file not found \font '.I am using Ubuntu 10.04. What is the problem actually ?

Comment: The given answer showing 4errors in my machine(ubuntu10.04) as follows ./myfile.tex:4:Undefined control sequence\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
./myfile.tex:4:Missing number,treated as zero\setmainfont{{FreeSerif}
./myfile.tex:4:Undefined control sequence\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
./myfile.tex:8:Missing number,treated as zero\setmainlanguage{bengali}

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

Don't mix high level commands (`fontspec`) with low level ones (`\font`). Here's how you can do in a better way; I've commented out the `\mukti` lines because I don't have the font

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
%\newfontfamily{\mukti}[Script=beng]{Mukti Narrow Bold}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}


\title{পাগলা দাশু}
\author{সুকুমার রায়}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

আমাদের স্কুলের যত ছাত্র তাহার মধ্যে এমন কেহই ছিল না, যে পাগলা দাশুকে
না চিনে। যে লোক আর কাহাকেও জানে না, সেও সকলের আগে পাগলা দাশুকে চিনিয়া
লয়। সেবার একজন নূতন দারোয়ান আসিল, একেবারে আনকোরা পাড়াগেঁয়ে লোক, কিন্তু
প্রথম যখন সে পাগলা দাশুর নাম শুনিল, তখনই সে আন্দাজে ঠিক ধরিয়া লইল যে,
এই ব্যক্তিই পাগলা দাশু। কারণ তার মুখের চেহারায়, কথাবার্তায়, চলনে চালনে
বোঝা যাইত যে তাহার মাথায় একটু 'ছিট' আছে। তাহার চোখদুটি গোল-গোল,
কানদুটা অনাবশ্যক রকমের বড়, মাথায় এক বস্তা ঝাঁকড়া চুল। চেহারাটা দেখিলেই
মনে হয়---

\vspace{10mm}

% Specific font can be used for any part of the document
%{\mukti বিঃদ্রঃ এই বাংলা পাতাটি লেখার জন্য XeTeX ব্যবহার করা হয়েছে।}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This showing 4errors in my machine(ubuntu10.04) as follows

Comment: This showing 4errors in my machine(ubuntu10.04) as follows ./myfile.tex:4:Undefined control sequence\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
./myfile.tex:4:Missing number,treated as zero\setmainfont{{FreeSerif}
./myfile.tex:4:Undefined control sequence\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
./myfile.tex:8:Missing number,treated as zero\setmainlanguage{bengali}

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar You have a very outdated TeX distribution.

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar As egreg says, the errors are arising as you have an old version of `fontspec`: it used to use a command `\setseriffont` rather than `\setmainfont`. I'd recommend [installing 'vanilla' TeX Live](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) as for complex scripts the updates to the binary part of TeX are also important.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do so in many languages is to use `fontspec` and `polyglossia` packages together. Unfortunately, `polyglossia`'s support for Bangla is rather limited. That's why I have written a new package `latexbangla` to specifically address Bangla related typesetting issues. Some of its features are -- automatic transition from Bangla to English and vice versa, patch for the unproportionate whitespace character issue for popular fonts, and many more (See the package documentation for full details).

Additionally, if you have any suggestion for new features, you can simply contact me and I shall look into it.

**Code sample:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,
            banglattfont=Siyam Rupali
           ]{latexbangla}

\title{পাগলা দাশু}
\author{সুকুমার রায়}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

আমাদের স্কুলের যত ছাত্র তাহার মধ্যে এমন কেহই ছিল না, যে পাগলা দাশুকে
না চিনে। যে লোক আর কাহাকেও জানে না, সেও সকলের আগে পাগলা দাশুকে চিনিয়া
লয়। সেবার একজন নূতন দারোয়ান আসিল, একেবারে আনকোরা পাড়াগেঁয়ে লোক, কিন্তু
প্রথম যখন সে পাগলা দাশুর নাম শুনিল, তখনই সে আন্দাজে ঠিক ধরিয়া লইল যে,
এই ব্যক্তিই পাগলা দাশু। কারণ তার মুখের চেহারায়, কথাবার্তায়, চলনে চালনে
বোঝা যাইত যে তাহার মাথায় একটু 'ছিট' আছে। তাহার চোখদুটি গোল-গোল,
কানদুটা অনাবশ্যক রকমের বড়, মাথায় এক বস্তা ঝাঁকড়া চুল। চেহারাটা দেখিলেই
মনে হয়---
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a last tip. The font Mukti Narrow is quite old and does not provide good support for LaTeX. You should consider downloading "modern" fonts like *Kalpurush*, *Siyam Rupali*, *Solaiman Lipi* or *Bangla* from [OmicronLab](http://omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html).

Comment: Package 'latexbangla' has been removed from CTAN. Thus, this answer is meaningless now!

Comment: Before calling an answer/package meaningless, you should have notified the author. Originally, I called my package 'banglatex', but had to rename it to 'latexbangla' due to a naming conflict. The later is available in CTAN, but the former is not.

Comment: @AdibHasan I am glad that you have contribute in LaTeX as Bangali. Thank you. But, I guess your font is bit bolder than [bangtex](http://www.saha.ac.in/theory/palashbaran.pal/bangtex/samples/samptex.pdf). Sorry, if I wrong.

Comment: @AdibHasan your package don't support `pdflatex` but I am comfortable in `pdflatex`.

Comment: @alhelal, it is not clear what you identified as "my bangla font". Both Kalpurush and Siyam Rupali were developed by OmicronLab (with which I have no ties). I used these fonts in the example above because they are freely available. However, with LaTeXbangla, you are free to use any unicode compatible bangla font. Also note that, `pdflatex` has no support for unicode. Consequently, there is no simple way to write in Bangla with it unless you are willing to write something like [this](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/bengali/bangtex/examples/samptex.tex).