# MiKTeX 2.9 problem with XeLaTeX and a Bengali script

Tags: xetex, miktex

I wanted to create a Bengali document using Latex. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 in windows XP. I installed all the fonts and the packages for MiKTeX 2.9. I copied the code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99659/32698) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103274/how-to-type-bengali-script-in-latex). Both of them are not working. Both the cases I got following error:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg"

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tl 
                        fontspec/Ligatures/Historical
l.8 ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}

?
```

At the end, it is producing a `.pdf` file but without any content. Could anybody please help me with this?

Comment: You need to update some packages (probably fontspec, perhaps l3kernel). In case of a multiuser installation: Run the update manager in admin *and* user mode to check for updates. But be careful: There are tons of new binaries in the update queue. It could be wise to wait a bit before updating them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. It is working now. Do you know how to configue TexMaker to support bengali script or any other unicode script? Same configuration(Encoding: UTF-8, Font: Kalpurush) in MikTex is working. But Texmaker Editor is unable to show the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update some packages (probably `fontspec`, perhaps `l3kernel`). In case of a multiuser installation: Run the update manager in admin *and* user mode to check for updates.