# Alphabet conversion chart

Tags: indic

In reference to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex) question about typing in English and getting output in Bengali (in the way done by the O.P) , can someone give me a conversion chart as to which combination of English characters correspond to which characters in Bengali?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the [`manual.tex` file from here](http://tug.ctan.org/language/bangtex/examples/) and compile it. A table is given on page 8. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: One of the most "perfect" answers I have ever got. Thank you very much.