# Problem with latex editing in Bengali

Tags: errors, polyglossia

When I'm going to run the following content in XeLaTeX mode in MikTeX:

[How to write Bengali in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335214/145161).

The following error comes up:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("bengali in latex.tex"
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
(latexbangla.sty
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\polyglossia\polyglossia.sty"
(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\makecmds\makecmds.sty)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex)

(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def
))
(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse
.sty) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\xetex.def"))))
Runaway argument?
{\dim_set:Nn ##1{\fontdimen ##2##3}\dim_compare:nNnT ##1={0pt}{\settoheight \ET
C.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \__cs_generate_from_si
gnature:nnNNNn.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1767       \int_case:nnn
                           #2
?
```

Along with following output

[image]

How do I remove the  `25x8X?` and `5555555555` above the desired portion?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you used to produce this error. And you don't need all of the console log in your question.

Comment: The spurious output is almost certainly the result of the error, so if you fix the error you will solve the problem. Try updating your distribution to the most recent version of the packages.