# How to write bangla with ornaments package in LaTeX?

Tags: languages, pgfornament

[image]

I want to write [bengali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language) in the place where text **Helal** is written. Related question [How to write Bengali in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex)
Code of the image is -

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
%\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,banglattfont=Siyam Rupali]{latexbangla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzrput}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} 
\begin{document}  
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   
\unitlength=1cm   

\begin{center}   
\begin{picture}(10,10)%
  \color{Blue}%
   \put(0,0){\framebox(10,10){%
   \rput[tl](-3,5){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}}%
   \rput[bl](-3,-5){\pgfornament[width=6cm,,symmetry=h]{71}}%
   \rput[tl](-5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}}%
   \rput[tr](5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=v]{63}}%
   \rput[bl](-5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=h]{63}}%
   \rput[br](5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=c]{63}}%
   \rput[bl]{-90}(-5,3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
   \rput[bl]{90}(5,-3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
   \rput(0,0){\Huge \color{Maroon}\textbf{Helal}}%
   \rput[b](0,0.5){\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}}%
   \rput[t](0,-0.5){\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}}%
%   \rput[tr]{-30}(-1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{57}}%
%   \rput[tl]{30}(1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{57}}}}% 
 }}
\end{picture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of things causing problems:

- The `latexbangla` package requires `xelatex`, it doesn't seem to work with `lualatex`.
- But `tikzrput` doesn't seem to work with `xelatex`.

So you have a couple of options I think:

1. Use normal TikZ code (as demonstrated in the `pgfornament` manual) instead of `\rput` from `tikzrput`.
2. Use something like Alan Munn's code from [How to write Bengali in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex/99659#99659) instead of the `latexbangla` package, and compile with `lualatex`.

## Option 1

Here is a code example for option 1, compile with `xelatex`. I used a different font as you can see in the options to `latexbangla`, so you might want to change that back. (The text used is Google's translation of the word "something" into Bengali.)

As you can see the code is actually quite similar, compare these two corresponding lines:

```
\rput[bl]{-90}(-5,3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
```

and

```
\node [anchor=south west,rotate=-90] at (-5,3) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
```

- Use `\node` instead of `\rput`
- Instead of `bl` for `b`ottom `l`eft, write `anchor=south west`. Similarly `north east` instead of `tr`, etc.
- For rotation, add `rotation=<angle>` inside the brackets after the `anchor` setting, instead of the extra argument used for `\rput`.
- Write `at` before the coordinate.
- End the line with a semicolon.

[image: output from xelatex]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Akaash,banglattfont=Akaash]{latexbangla}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\begin{document}  
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   

\begin{center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={inner sep=0}]
   \draw [Blue] (-5,-5) rectangle +(10,10);
   \node [anchor=north west] at (-3,5) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}};
   \node [anchor=south west] at (-3,-5) {\pgfornament[width=6cm,,symmetry=h]{71}};
   \node [anchor=north west] at (-5,5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
   \node [anchor=north east] at (5,5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=v]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south west] at (-5,-5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=h]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south east] at (5,-5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=c]{63}};
   \node [anchor=south west,rotate=-90] at (-5,3) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
   \node [anchor=south west,rotate=90] at (5,-3) {\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
   \node [Maroon,font=\Huge\bfseries] at (0,0) {কিছু};
   \node [anchor=south] at (0,0.5) {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}};
   \node [anchor=north] at (0,-0.5) {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}};
%   \node [anchor=north east,rotate=-30] at (-1,2.5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{57}};
%   \node [anchor=north west,rotate=30] at (1,2.5) {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{57}};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

## Option 2

Compile with `lualatex`.

[image: output from lualatex]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%%%%%%%%
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99659/586 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzrput}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} 
\begin{document}  
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   
\unitlength=1cm   

\begin{center}   
\begin{picture}(10,10)%
  \color{Blue}%
   \put(0,0){\framebox(10,10){%
   \rput[tl](-3,5){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}}%
   \rput[bl](-3,-5){\pgfornament[width=6cm,,symmetry=h]{71}}%
   \rput[tl](-5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}}%
   \rput[tr](5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=v]{63}}%
   \rput[bl](-5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=h]{63}}%
   \rput[br](5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=c]{63}}%
   \rput[bl]{-90}(-5,3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
   \rput[bl]{90}(5,-3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
   \rput(0,0){\Huge \color{Maroon}\textbf{কিছু}}%
   \rput[b](0,0.5){\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}}%
   \rput[t](0,-0.5){\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}}%
%   \rput[tr]{-30}(-1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{57}}%
%   \rput[tl]{30}(1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{57}}% 
 }}
\end{picture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your 2nd option output bengali text is different from the input?

Comment: @alhelal Ehm, no idea why that would be the case. But use the first one then, if that is correct.