# bold and italic not working in Bangla font

Tags: bold, italic

I am using polyglossia for Bangla. But I cannot do bold or italic. May be the Bangla font "Kalpurush"   is causing the issue as English "Times New Roman" font is just working fine. Here is a download link to "[kalpurush.ttf](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/kalpurush.ttf)" file.
can any one help? Thanks in advance. :)

here's the code.

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Kalpurush}
\begin{document}

সাধারন ফন্ট, \textbf{বল্ড ফন্ট}, \textit{ইটালিক ফন্ট}\\

regular font, \textbf{bold font}, \textit{italic font}\\

\englishfont{regular font, \textbf{bold font.}, \textit{italic font}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The font doesn't appear to have the required forms. A single `.ttf` file contains just one shape/weight.

Comment: You could try the FakeBold and FakeSlant options, see the documentation of fontspec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am really new to latex. I tried but could not figure out how fontspec really works. It would be a huge help if you could post a answer using fontspec.

Comment: you are already using fontspec. I don't have your font and can't test. Try something like `\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,BoldFont={Kalpurush},BoldFeatures={FakeBold=5},ItalicFont={Kalpurush}, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=5}]{Kalpurush}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a single instance of the font, in regular weight, so no boldface is available.

If I use a different Bengali font, I get boldface. No italics, though: is it used in Bengali?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Bangla MN}[
  Script=Bengali,
  BoldFont=* Bold,
  ItalicFont=*, % just not to get annoying warnings
]

\begin{document}

সাধারন ফন্ট, \textbf{বল্ড ফন্ট}, \textit{ইটালিক ফন্ট}

regular font, \textbf{bold font}, \textit{italic font}

\englishfont{regular font, \textbf{bold font.}, \textit{italic font}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by the *bangla* package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{bangla}

\begin{document}

\banglatext{সাধারন ফন্ট}, \banglabold{বল্ড ফন্ট}, \banglaitalic{ইটালিক ফন্ট}

\end{document}
```

[image]