# How to add latexbangla in book document class?

Tags: xetex, header-footer

When I am using the latexbangla package

```
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Siyam Rupali,
feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla}. 
\newfontfamily{\bengalifontsf}[Script=Bengali]{Noto Sans Bengali}
```

in the following book documentation class, the header footer is not working.

**MWE:**

```
 \documentclass[twoside,12pt,english]{book}
    %\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Siyam Rupali, feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla} % to write bengali in latex
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{color}
    \definecolor{marron}{RGB}{60,30,10}
    \definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{0,80,0}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wallpaper}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    tmargin=5cm, 
    bmargin=5cm, 
    lmargin=5cm, 
    rmargin=3cm,
    headheight=1.5cm,
    headsep=0.8cm,
    footskip=0.5cm}
    
    \usepackage{fourier-orns}
    
    \newcommand{\ornpar}{\noindent \textcolor{darkgray}{ \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright \decofourleft \decothreeleft  \aldineright \decotwo \floweroneleft \decoone}}}
    
    \makeatletter
    \def\headrule{{\color{darkgray}\raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{~~~\decofourleft \decotwo\decofourright~~~} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{ \leafleft}}}
    \makeatother
    
    \fancyhf{}
    
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
   \newcommand{\estcab}[1]{\itshape\textcolor{marron}{\nouppercase #1}}
   \fancyhead[LO]{\estcab{\rightmark}} % malo cuando no hay section ~~~ \thesection
   \fancyfoot[RE]{\ornpar   \\ \large  \sffamily\bf \textcolor{darkgray}{\thepage ~~~ \reflectbox{\leafNE}}  \hfill}
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vspace{-0.5em}\noindent\textcolor{marron}{\decosix \raisebox{2.9pt}{\line(1,0){100}} \lefthand} \vspace{.5em} }
    \usepackage[hang,splitrule]{footmisc}
    \addtolength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.3cm}
    \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm} 
    
    %\newfontfamily{\bengalifontsf}[Script=Bengali]{Noto Sans Bengali}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \newpage
    \section{New Section}
    \end{document}
```

Without using  latexbangla package, everything is working fine. But I want to use latexbangla and the header footer should be the same as below.

[image]
How do I do it?

Comment: hm. I'm rather sure that I wrote already somewhere in a comment that latexbangla is doing quite odd things. If you want to use it you will have to debug it.

Comment: Perhaps the bug is not fixed yet: (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544315/you-cant-use-macro-parameter-character-error-in-latexbangla-and-polyglossia). Unrelated - (1) There is much useless code in the MWE (2) copy-pasting code without understanding it or adjusting it is unwise (3) after removing all copy-paste errors, it works OK with polyglossia and fontspec with bangla text, which implies that it should work OK also with latexbangla once the bug is fixed.