# Nested ordered list numbering style in Bengali

Tags: numbering, lists, babel

I am working on a large document in Bangla using this package setting. This changes the section and subsection numbers to Bengali. However, it doesn't change the numbering style to Bengali for nested lists. My desired output is shown in the figure:

[image]

But I got this using the following MWE. As you can see from the image, for the nested list, English alphabets are used. I want to replace those with the Bengali alphabets (ক, খ, গ, etc). How can this be done? It is also helpful if third level nested listing is possible!

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,showtrims]{memoir}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563720/change-numbering-style-to-bengali-in-nested-ordered-list/563725#563725
%https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-bengali.html

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import,onchar = fonts ids,maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}
%\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}
%\babelprovide[mapdigits,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

%\usepackage[bengali, provide=*]{babel}
%\babelprovide[mapdigits]{bengali}  % or alternatively maparabic

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item আইটেম ১
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item নেস্টেড আইটেম ১
        \item নেস্টেড আইটেম ২
    \end{enumerate}
    \item আইটেম ২
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note: I have already tried [Change numbering style to Bengali in nested ordered list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563720/change-numbering-style-to-bengali-in-nested-ordered-list/563725#563725) and got nothing.

Comment: You’re trying to import Bengali with `\babelprovide` twice, using different options.

Comment: @Davislor The options are not co-related and it works fine. Is there any performance issue?

Comment: I have edited my code using single `\babelprovide`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of surfing and reading documentations, I came up with a solution.

Adding `main` option to `\babelprovide` command solved the problem. It's peculiar, but works at last.

Edited MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,showtrims]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main,onchar = fonts ids,maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali} %% <--- here is the solution :D 
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

%\babelprovide[main]{bengali}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item আইটেম ১
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item নেস্টেড আইটেম ১
        \item নেস্টেড আইটেম ২
    \end{enumerate}
    \item আইটেম ২
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: Without `main`, you never actually change the language of your document. It mostly works because the `onchar=` option switches when you actually type in the Bengali script, but this doesn’t change the meaning of commands such as `\alph`. Those still use default English settings.

Comment: If you want only some parts of your document in Bengali, you can switch those with `\begin{otherlanguage}{bengali}`.

Comment: Thankkkkkkkkkkkk