# LaTeXbangla package is not working in Overleaf

Tags: xetex, packages, languages, overleaf

I am trying to write a bilingual (Bangla+English) document using [LaTeXbangla](https://github.com/Neehan/LaTeXbangla) package.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, 
            banglattfont=Siyam Rupali]{latexbangla}
\begin{document}
পিথাগোরাস(Pythagoras)-এর উপপাদ্যটি হল,\\
\textit{সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজের উপর অঙ্কিত  
বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফল অপর দুই বাহুর উপর অঙ্কিত বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফলের সমষ্টির সমান।} \\
অর্থাৎ কোন সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজ $c$ এবং অপর দুই বাহু $a$ এবং $b$ হলে,
\[c^2=a^2+b^2\]
লক্ষ্য করুন, এখন পর্যন্ত টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ} ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হয়েছে।\\
\texttt{এবার, টেলিটাইপ(Teletype) টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{সিয়াম রূপালী} ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হল।}\\
পুনরায় টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ  ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত  হচ্ছে।}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with Miktex XeLaTeX (Windows 10), it's giving me the output perfectly. But with Overleaf XeLaTeX, it's not working. Why is it happening? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Does changing the engine to TeX Live 2020 work?

Comment: @Davislor I just tried it it times out, I guess the font isn't there and it's re-running fc-cache but as it times out you don't get any usable message.

Comment: @raf if the fonts you are using are freely available you can upload them to your project otherwise you need to pick a font that is available to the linux texlive being used by overleaf.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good instincts! When I press the “Show raw logs” button, it does give the font-not-found messages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (as David Carlisle correctly intuited) is that Overleaf does not have those fonts installed.  If you click the “Show raw logs” button, you will see the error message.

Thanks to @imnothere for linking [the list of Bengali fonts available in Overleaf.](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Bengali)  You should be able to substitute any of these.  Some will need the `AutoFakeBold =` or `AutoFakeSlant =` options.

As David Carlisle suggested in a comment, if the font you want to use is free, you can put a copy of the font file in your project folder.

### A Solution

Downloading the font files to your project folder was not enough to get `latexbangla` to work.  (It might be possible to hack a fix with `\defaultfontfeatures`.)  What I ended up doing instead was write a new solution that uses `babel` in LuaLaTeX from 2020 or later.

Since you use both bold and italic, but the fonts you linked me to come with neither, I had `fontspec` fake both bold and slanted.

First, create a new sub-folder named fonts and upload both `kalpurush.ttf` and `Siyamrupah.ttf` to it.  The following MWE now works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[bidi=basic,
            layout=sectioning.tabular,
            nil
           ]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

%% Kalpurush and Siyam Rupali are free for
%% download at:
%% https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html
\defaultfontfeatures[kalpurush]{
  Path = ./fonts/ ,
  Extension = .ttf ,
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2 ,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.2 }
\defaultfontfeatures[Siyamrupali]{
  Path = ./fonts/ ,
  Extension = .ttf ,
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2 ,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.2 }

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernBook}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernMonoBook}

\babelprovide[import=bn,
              main,
              onchar=ids fonts
             ]{bangla}
\babelfont[bangla]{rm}
          {kalpurush}
\babelfont[bangla]{sf}
          {Siyamrupali}
\babelfont[bangla]{tt}
          {Siyamrupali}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\begin{document}
পিথাগোরাস(Pythagoras)-এর উপপাদ্যটি হল,\\
\textit{সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজের উপর অঙ্কিত  
বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফল অপর দুই বাহুর উপর অঙ্কিত বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফলের সমষ্টির সমান।} \\
অর্থাৎ কোন সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজ $c$ এবং অপর দুই বাহু $a$ এবং $b$ হলে,
\[c^2=a^2+b^2\]
লক্ষ্য করুন, এখন পর্যন্ত টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ} ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হয়েছে।\\
\texttt{এবার, টেলিটাইপ(Teletype) টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{সিয়াম রূপালী} ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হল।}\\
পুনরায় টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ  ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত  হচ্ছে।}
\end{document}
```

I warn you that the fake-bold teletype text has some terrible hinting, which makes it look ugly in this low-res image. It’s not nearly so bad when you see the full-size PDF.

[image: Kalpurush/Siyam Rupali sample]

The Siyam rupali font has some trouble displaying English text in parentheses.  Switching to Mukti Narrow or Mitra fixed them, or it’s possible to configure `babel` to automatically switch to the English font whenever it sees `(` or `)`.

The layout will look much better if you remove the `\\` breaks and let the LaTeX line-breaking algorithm work.  The `microtype` package (with font protrusion off if you mind the large number of benign warning messages it gives you when you load a Bangla font) might also help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[bidi=basic,
            layout=sectioning.tabular,
            nil
           ]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

%% Kalpurush and Siyam Rupali are free for
%% download at:
%% https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html
\defaultfontfeatures[kalpurush]{
%  Path = ./fonts/ ,
  Extension = .ttf ,
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2 ,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.2 }
\defaultfontfeatures[Siyamrupali]{
% Path = ./fonts/ ,
  Extension = .ttf ,
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2 ,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.2 }
\defaultfontfeatures[Mitra]{
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2
}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernBook}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernMonoBook}

\babelprovide[import=bn,
              main,
              onchar=ids fonts
             ]{bangla}
\babelfont[bangla]{rm}
          {kalpurush}
\babelfont[bangla]{sf}
          {MuktiNarrow}
\babelfont[bangla]{tt}
          {Mitra}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\begin{document}
পিথাগোরাস(Pythagoras)-এর উপপাদ্যটি হল,
\textit{সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজের উপর অঙ্কিত  
বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফল অপর দুই বাহুর উপর অঙ্কিত বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফলের সমষ্টির সমান।}
অর্থাৎ কোন সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজ $c$ এবং অপর দুই বাহু $a$ এবং $b$ হলে,

\[c^2=a^2+b^2\]

লক্ষ্য করুন, এখন পর্যন্ত টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ, ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হয়েছে।}
\texttt{এবার, টেলিটাইপ (Teletype)টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{সিয়াম রূপালী} ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হল।}
পুনরায় টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ  ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত  হচ্ছে।}
\end{document}
```

[image: Kalpurush/Mitra sample]

And a solution using only fonts installed on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[bidi=basic,
            layout=sectioning.tabular,
            nil
           ]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernBook}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernMonoBook}

\defaultfontfeatures[LohitBengali]{
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2, 
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.175 }
\defaultfontfeatures[MitraMono]{
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2 }

\babelprovide[import=bn,
              main,
              onchar=ids fonts
             ]{bangla}
\babelfont[bangla]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{LohitBengali}
\babelfont[bangla]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{MuktiNarrow}
\babelfont[bangla]{tt}
          [Language=Default, Scale=0.75]{MitraMono}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\begin{document}
পিথাগোরাস(Pythagoras)-এর উপপাদ্যটি হল,
\textit{সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজের উপর অঙ্কিত  
বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফল অপর দুই বাহুর উপর অঙ্কিত বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফলের সমষ্টির সমান।} 
অর্থাৎ কোন সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজ $c$ এবং অপর দুই বাহু $a$ এবং $b$ হলে,

\[c^2=a^2+b^2\]

লক্ষ্য করুন, এখন পর্যন্ত টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ} ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হয়েছে।
\texttt{এবার, টেলিটাইপ (Teletype) টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{সিয়াম রূপালী} ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হল।}
পুনরায় টেক্সট প্রদর্শনের জন্য \textbf{কালপুরুষ  ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত  হচ্ছে।}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the FreeSerif, FreeSans don't display the words properly.
The fonts (TTF files of Kalpurush and Siyam Rupali) that I want to use are available online here: https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html
Can you kindly show me how to use the uploaded font files with latexbangla in overleaf?

Comment: @raf I’ve posted an updated solution that at least finds the correct fonts on Overleaf, although I think the text got garbled somewhere along the way. It does *not* use the exact same packages as your original MWE, so I’m not sure whether it will meet your needs. (For example, `latexbangla` provides certain theorem environments that you would need to define yourself. And it runs in LuaLaTeX, not XeLaTeX.) I did get it to compile your MWE.

Comment: @raf I had some trouble displaying English inside parentheses with Siyam Rupali; this seems to be a problem with the font, and switching fonts fixed it. It would also be possible to tell Babel to always display `(` and `)` from the English font. The layout seems to be much better if I remove the ``\\`` breaks and allow the line-breaking algorithm to do its work. Babel has hyphenation patterns, and `microtype` also helps.

Comment: List of fonts for Bangla/Bengali: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Bengali

Comment: @imnothere Thank you! That’s very useful.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Davislor.
Another problem I am facing while writing/typing Bangla in Overleaf editor in Google Chrome. The same issue for Firefox is discussed here: https://support.mozilla.org/bg/questions/1263396

Comment: @raf I noticed what I think is the same issue. I ended up editing offline and pasting into the Overleaf window.

Comment: @Davislor, I contacted the Overleaf support team about this cursor offset issue. They suggested trying the rich text editor. But it didn't work for me. So same as you, I ended up using my offline LaTeX editors for Bangla writing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have found that the font 'Kalpurush' is added to [the list of Overleaf-supported Bengali fonts](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Bengali). The following MWE is perfectly compiled with Overleaf XeLaTeX (Texlive 2022):

```
\documentclass{article}

% latexbangla with all features
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, 
            banglattfont=Kalpurush
           ]{latexbangla}  
% activate polyglossia
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali, 
                    changecounternumbering=true
                   ]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
            
\begin{document}
পিথাগোরাস (Pythagoras)-এর উপপাদ্যটি হল,\\
\textit{সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজের উপর অঙ্কিত বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফল অপর দুই বাহুর উপর অঙ্কিত বর্গক্ষেত্রের ক্ষেত্রফলের সমষ্টির সমান।} \\
অর্থাৎ কোন সমকোণী ত্রিভুজের অতিভুজ $c$ এবং অপর দুই বাহু $a$ এবং $b$ হলে,
\[c^2=a^2+b^2\]
\end{document}
```

Till now (September 7, 2022), the font `Siam Rupali` is not supported/available in Overleaf. Also, I don't feel the need to use a separate teletype font in Bangla texts. So, I have set the same font in both options of `latexbangla` package in the above MWE.