# write bengali and english text in a single line

Tags: tables, pdftex, packages

I have a table in excel which contains both Bengali and English text. I want to convert this to latex but `texstudio` cannot seem to display mixed text, either it displays only the Bengali text or only the English text.

I have tried [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex) but it doesn't work for both languages at a time.

The following code only shows the Bengali part and not the English part. How do I make it show both?

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{buetcseugthesis}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


% Uncomment the following lines if you need to write in Bangla
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\newfontscript{BengaliOpenTypeOld}{beng}
\newfontscript{BengaliOpenTypeNew}{bng2}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}[Script=BengaliOpenTypeNew]
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]\centering
    \caption{Generated by Spread-LaTeX}\label{tab: }
    \scriptsize
    \begin{bengali}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        text1 &ডায়াবেটিস রুগীদের ডায়াবেটিস থেকে কিভাবে ওষুধ ছাড়াই ভালো থাকবেন। \\
        text2 &মায়ের ডায়াবেটিসে নবজাতকের ঝুঁকি দ্বিগুণ #ইত্তেফাক #নিউজ #ittefaq #ডায়াবেটিস \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{bengali}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [the answer I gave to the earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561540/61644) work for you? If not, you could either use `ucharclasses` in XeLaTeX, or wrap the lines in `\textbengali` or `\textenglish`.

Comment: your earlier answer didn't work

Comment: Okay. What error did you get?

Comment: `Package babel Error: Bad option `bidi=basic'. Either you have misspelled the(babel) key or there is a previous setting of `bidi'. \ProcessOptions*`

`Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option. ... try to proceed from here, type x to quit.}`

`Package babel Error: Unknown language "english". Either you have(babel) install it or just rerun the file, respectively. \select@language {english}`

Comment: These are some of the errors generated

Comment: Are you compiling it with LuaLaTeX in a recent installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119694/discussion-between-afsara-ben-and-davislor).

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use [pdflatex_bengali](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/pdflatex_bengali) based on the [bangtex](http://www.saha.ac.in/theory/palashbaran.pal/bangtex/bangtex.html) package.

#### Quickstart Guide

- Put the [mf](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/tree/main/mf) folder along with all its contents in the same directory as your LaTeX source code.
- Put the [bangla_commands.tex](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/blob/main/bangla_commands.tex) file in the same directory as your LaTeX source code.
- Put `\input{bangla_commands}` in the preamble of your LaTeX source code
- When you write বাংলা enclose it within the `\bng` command like this `{\bng baNNGla \*l*ikhun}` which should output বাংলা লিখুন
- The `\bng` command can be replaced by commands specifying other sizes, and this is outlined in the
  [demo.tex](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/blob/main/demo.tex) and
  [demo.pdf](https://github.com/aritraghsh09/bangtex_overleaf/blob/main/demo.pdf) files.
- A simple example document is shown below

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\title{Bengali Test}
\author{{\lbng Airt/r \*gh*eaSh}}

\input{bangla_commands}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Example}

This is english {\bng baNNGla \*l*ikhun}

\end{document}
```