# Does anyone knows that how to write exam question paper's in Bangla language?

Tags: languages

**Hi,**

I want to write exam question paper's (M.C.Q) with latexbangla. If anyone who knows how write Bangla Question Paper's with LaTeX, Please help me!

Comment: Please see if the answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex can help.

Comment: There is summary on how to write in Bangla in the `babel` site: https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-bengali.html .