# How can I use certain font for a certain character set?

Tags: fonts

Suppose I writing a document that contains some Latin and Devanagari script. Now I want to set a certain font (for example - [Hind Siliguri](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Hind+Siliguri)) for the Devanagari script as the default Latin font doesn't contain glyphs of Devanagari script. How can set a certain font for a certain character set in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a short TeX code of your document you have so far (use `blindtext` or simular to generate dummy text for the example code)?

Comment: Which engine do you use?

Comment: Since that appears to be a Bengali font, [this should work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-write-bengali-in-latex/561540#561540) if you change which font you load with `\babelfont`. That answer requires LuaLaTeX from 2019 or later, but it could also be done in XeLaTeX.