# How to get section numbers and page numbers with Bengali numerals in latex or xetex?

Tags: sectioning, page-numbering, indic

How i can give section numbers and page numbers with Bengali numerals in latex?

Comment: Maybe this works you ... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70414/how-to-get-devanagari-numerals-in-latex-or-xetex

Comment: This should be a straight-forward `\renewcommand` of `\thesection` and `\thepage`.

Comment: i'm a beginner. if anybody give an example, it would be great.

Comment: @Masud Please, add a minimal example to play with.

Comment: i'm trying with similar code(last one).......
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70414/how-to-get-devanagari-numerals-in-latex-or-xetex

Comment: instead of hindi i'm trying with bengali.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Enrico’s answer in the other question, provided you define a macro that outputs the Bengali numerals, as in the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\bengalidigits#1{\expandafter\@bengali@digits #1@}
\def\@bengali@digits#1{%
  \ifx @#1
  \else
    \ifx0#1০\else\ifx1#1১\else\ifx2#1২\else\ifx3#1৩\else\ifx4#1৪\else\ifx5#1৫\else\ifx6#1৬\else\ifx7#1৭\else\ifx8#1৮\else\ifx9#1৯\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \expandafter\@bengali@digits
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\def\bengalinumber#1{\bengalidigits{\number#1}}
\def\bengalinumeral#1{\bengalinumber{\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\renewcommand\thesection{\bengalinumeral{section}}
\renewcommand\thepage{\bengalinumeral{page}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lohit Bengali}

\begin{document}

\section{বৈশাখ}

\section{জ্যৈষ্ঠ}

\section{আষাঢ়}

\section{শ্রাবণ}

\section{ভাদ্র}

\section{আশ্বিন}

\end{document}
```

With this code I get the following result:[image: Example with Bengali section and page numbers]

Note in particular the Bengali digit 1 as the page number.

I’ll make the Bengali digit code in a package as part of Polyglossia.

Comment: Thank u so much.But is there any easier way to solve?
if u make the Bengali digit code in a package as part of Polyglossia. how can i know u did? 
thanks again in advance :)

Comment: I’ll let you know when it’s done :-)

Comment: Have you finished doing Bengali digit code in Polyglossia? :-) 
(I can hardly wait to see!)

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer Any plans of adding this? People are [still asking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377223/how-can-i-change-the-chapter-numbers-in-bengali-numerals-words) questions about this feature… See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300070/adding-full-non-english-unicode-language-bengali-support-to-polyglossia).

Answer (score 3):

There is a `gloss-bengali.ldf` file, such that, when you use the `polyglossia` command: 
`\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}`, the numbering for page and for `section` down to `subparagraph` are changed to Bengali digits. Bengali names for the parts of a document are also in the file.

Some random text:

[image: bengali sections]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.5]{Noto Serif Bengali}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\begin{document}
\today
\tableofcontents
\section{কখগঘ কাকিকী কেকৈককোকৌ}
\subsection{ক}
০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯ \bengalidigits{123 456 789} 
\newpage
\section{কখগঘ কাকিকী কেকৈককোকৌ}
কখগঘ
\subsection{ক}
কখগঘ
\subsubsection{ক}
কখগঘ
\subsubsection{ক}
কখগঘ
\subsubsection{ক}
কখগঘ
\end{document}
```

From the `.ldf` code, it should be straightforward to add the `chapter`, `figure`, `table` and `footnote` counters. Which leaves `csquotes` package quotation marks , perhaps equation numbering, and maybe the `biblatex` bibliography (and numeric citation style). And a note in the `.ldf` says the calendar still has to be done.

Certainly, section numbers and page numbers are available.