# How to use bangla number in \label and \ref environment for equation?

Tags: cross-referencing, indic

I want to use [the Bengali numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_numerals) for equation referencing. Can anybody explain with example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which TeX engine you use -- pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX? -- and how you've implemented Bangla numbering style for equations. Once the equation numbering is set, the work of cross-referencing equations is fairly straightforward.

Comment: A stackexchange portal for Bangla language has been proposed in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109460/bangla-or-bengali-language-learners).

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/numbering-enumerate-environments-and-pages-with-devanagari-alphabet/366363#366363

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246881/how-to-get-section-numbers-and-page-numbers-with-bengali-numerals-in-latex-or-xe