# Numbering enumerate environments and pages with Devanagari alphabet

Tags: xetex, numbering, enumerate, page-numbering, indic

I am building a large document with xelatex-devanagari. Still, page numbers in the frontmatter defaults to roman numbering. How can I change them to Devanagari custom alphabetic numbering like **अ,आ...** or **क,ख,ग...**?

Similar numbering needed for enumerated lists. Presently, first level of enumeration shows Devanagari numerals. What is the best method to achieve Devanagari alphabetic numbering in other levels also?

Sample code -

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Sanskrit 2003}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{अध्यायः}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{विषयसूची}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{भूमिका}

\mainmatter
\chapter{सङ्ग्रहः}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item प्रथमम्
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item द्वितीयम्
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item तृतीयम्
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item चतुर्थम्
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: enumeration demo]

Comment: Thanks for adding the example. It raises new questions: with the default settings, there are multiple series: digits (`1, 2, 3…`), roman numerals (`i, ii, iii…`), lowercase letters (`a, b, c…`), uppercase letters (`A, B, C…`). The first of these should of course become `१, २, ३…`. What about the others? Which of them should become `अ,आ…` or `क,ख,ग…`?

Comment: As you know, Devanagari does not have that case differences. So, those who use it must differentiate each level. I like the way,
* १, २, ३... for 1st level
* क, ख, ग... for 2nd level
* (१), (२), (३)... for 3rd level and
* (क), (ख), (ग)... for 4th level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How counters are displayed

In LaTeX, a counter is displayed in one of several “styles”, given by `\arabic`, `\roman`, `\Roman`, `\alph`, `\Alph`, and `\fnsymbol`. (See [Chapter 13 *Counters*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#Counters) in [`texdoc latex2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.pdf), or File m *ltcounts.dtx* in [`texdoc source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf), or [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Counters&oldid=3007015#Counter_style)/[here](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/counters.htm)/[here](http://www.ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-3.html)/[here](https://texblog.org/2007/07/25/counters-in-latex/).) Of these, `\fnsymbol` is just symbols used for footnotes (`*, ‡, ‡, §, ¶, ∥, **, ††, ‡‡`), so it is enough to redefine the others.

For example, by default `\Alph` is defined via `\@Alph` which is defined as

```
\def\@Alph#1{%
 \ifcase#1\or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or
  K\or L\or M\or N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or
   Y\or Z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
```

We can modify this to always use Devanagari consonants `क, ख, ग, …` everywhere, in place of Roman numerals or letters from the Latin alphabet. (You may also want Devanagari vowels `अ, आ, इ, ई, …` for one of those; it's your preference.)

#### How labels in enumerations are displayed

The labels for `enumerate` at each level are given by `\labelenumi`, `\labelenumii`, `\labelenumiii`, and `\labelenumiv`. (See [section 8.7 *enumerate*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#enumerate) in `texdoc latex2e`, or 54.6 *Itemize and Enumerate* in [`texdoc source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf).)

For example, by default `\labelenumii` is defined as `(\theenumii)` where `\theenumii` is in turn defined as `\@alph\c@enumii`, which is why at the second level of nesting in lists, you see labels like `(a)`. You can redefine these too, if you (say) want the parentheses or periods in different places.

#### Putting it together

Here is your sample LaTeX source from the question, with appropriate modifications (the part within `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` is the only change):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Sanskrit 2003}

\makeatletter
% Always use Devanagari consonants for alph/Alph/roman/Roman styles.
\def\devanagari@alph#1{%
 \ifcase#1\or क\or ख\or ग\or घ\or ङ\or च\or छ\or ज\or झ\or ञ\or
  ट\or ठ\or ड\or ढ\or ण\or त\or थ\or द\or ध\or न\or प\or फ\or ब\or भ\or म\or
   य\or र\or ल\or व\or श\or ष\or स\or ह\else\@ctrerr\fi}
% Imitating xgreek.sty and xepersian.sty
\let\@alph\devanagari@alph
\let\@Alph\devanagari@alph
\let\@roman\devanagari@alph
\let\@Roman\devanagari@alph

% Change appearance of enumerate at levels 2, 3, 4.
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii.} % Instead of: (\theenumii)
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{(\theenumiii)} % Instead of: \theenumiii.
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\@arabic\c@enumiii} % Instead of: \@roman\c@enumiii
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{(\theenumiv)} % Instead of: \theenumiv.
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{अध्यायः}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{विषयसूची}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{भूमिका}

\mainmatter
\chapter{सङ्ग्रहः}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item प्रथमम्
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item द्वितीयम्
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item तृतीयम्
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item चतुर्थम्
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Running this with `xelatex` gives Devanagari-consonant page numbers instead of roman numerals (for the front matter), and, for the enumerate, the following:
[image: enumerate environment with Devanagari labels]