# Page-numbering in the frontmatter for Marathi

Tags: page-numbering, polyglossia

This is a follow-up question of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374432/page-number-style-for-marathi) that @Sushant asked. The answer for this question given by @Allan Munn works perfectly- thanks Allan Munn! I am using this answer while writing Marathi documents using the package Polyglossia. Here are my questions:
writing the page numbers in words for `frontmatter`-content is the tradition in Marathi book-making.

1. How can I use Allan Munn's answers in the above question *globally* on my machine? (I guess that I shall have to do some modification for that in the marathi.ldf file that Polyglossia uses for Marathi-typesetting.)
2. How can I request the maintainers of Polyglossia to include these changes, say for numbers till 200, and make them available to everyone? (I hope that this is possible).

If needed, following are 1-100 numbers (copied from Allan Munn's example that I use):

```
एक\or दोन\or तीन\or चार\or पाच \or सहा\or सात\or आठ\or
  नऊ\or दहा\or अकरा\or बारा\or तेरा\or चौदा\or पंधरा\or सोळा\or सतरा\or
  अठरा\or एकोणीस\or वीस\or एकवीस\or बावीस\or तेवीस\or चोवीस\or पंचवीस\or
  सव्वीस\or सत्तावीस\or अठाव्वीस\or एकोणतीस\or तीस\or एकतीस\or बत्तीस\or
  तेहेत्तीस \or चौतीस \or पस्तीस \or छत्तीस \or सतदिस \or अडतीस \or
  एकोणचाळीस \or चाळीस \or एक्केचाळीस \or बेचाळीस \or त्रेचाळीस \or चौवेचाळीस
  \or पंचेचाळीस \or सेहेचाळीस \or सत्तेचाळीस \or अठ्ठेचाळीस \or एकोणपन्नास \or
  पन्नास \or एक्कावन्न \or बावन्न \or त्रेपन्न \or चोपन्न \or पंचावन्न \or छपन्न
  \or सत्तावन्न \or अठ्ठावन्न \or एकोणसाठ \or साठ \or एकसष्ठ \or बासष्ठ \or
  त्रेसष्ट \or चौसष्ठ \or पासष्ठ \or सहासष्ठ \or सदुष्ठ \or अडुसष्ठ \or एकोणसत्तर
  \or सत्तर \or एकाहत्तर \or बहात्तर \or त्र्याहत्तर \or चौऱ्याहत्तर \or
  पंच्याहत्तर \or शहात्तर \or सत्याहत्तर \or अठ्याहत्तर \or एकोणऐशी \or ऐंशी
  \or एक्याऐंशी \or ब्याऐंशी \or त्र्याऐंशी \or चौऱ्याऐंशी \or पंच्याऐंशी \or
  शह्यांशी \or सत्यांऐंशी \or अठ्ठ्याऐंशी \or एकोणनव्वद \or नव्वद \or एक्याण्णव
  \or ब्याण्णव \or त्र्याण्णव \or चौऱ्याण्णव \or पंच्याण्णव \or शहाण्णव \or
  सत्याण्णव \or अठ्याण्णव \or नव्याण्णव \or शंभर
```

After hundred, they are counted as

```
एकशे-एक (101), एकशे-दोन (102),..., एकशे-नव्याण्णव (199), दोनशे (200)
```

Thus, in general, for a number "n" between 1-99, both inclusive, the number 100+n term is written  as एकशे-"n in Marathi".

Comment: `\frontmatter` does `\pagenumbering{roman}`. One could conceive that `marathi.ldf` patches `\frontmatter` to replace it with `\pagenumbering{marathiwords}`. On the other hand, `memoir` doesn't do `\pagenumbering{roman}` in `\frontmatter`, but in an auxiliary macro. So you'd need different patches for different classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add patches to `\frontmatter` (good for `book` and `scrbook` and perhaps for other classes based on them, provided they don't redefine `\frontmatter`) and to `\@memfront` for `memoir`. Such patches might be added to `marathi.ldf`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{marathi}
\setmainfont{Devanagari MT}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Devanagari MT}

% this should go in marathi.ldf
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@marathiwords}[1]{\ifcase#1%
  एक\or दोन\or तीन\or चार\or पाच \or सहा\or सात\or आठ\or
  नऊ\or दहा\or अकरा\or बारा\or तेरा\or चौदा\or पंधरा\or सोळा\or सतरा\or
  अठरा\or एकोणीस\or वीस\or एकवीस\or बावीस\or तेवीस\or चोवीस\or पंचवीस\or
  सव्वीस\or सत्तावीस\or अठाव्वीस\or एकोणतीस\or तीस\or एकतीस\or बत्तीस\or
  तेहेत्तीस \or चौतीस \or पस्तीस \or छत्तीस \or सतदिस \or अडतीस \or
  एकोणचाळीस \or चाळीस \or एक्केचाळीस \or बेचाळीस \or त्रेचाळीस \or चौवेचाळीस
  \or पंचेचाळीस \or सेहेचाळीस \or सत्तेचाळीस \or अठ्ठेचाळीस \or एकोणपन्नास \or
  पन्नास \or एक्कावन्न \or बावन्न \or त्रेपन्न \or चोपन्न \or पंचावन्न \or छपन्न
  \or सत्तावन्न \or अठ्ठावन्न \or एकोणसाठ \or साठ \or एकसष्ठ \or बासष्ठ \or
  त्रेसष्ट \or चौसष्ठ \or पासष्ठ \or सहासष्ठ \or सदुष्ठ \or अडुसष्ठ \or एकोणसत्तर
  \or सत्तर \or एकाहत्तर \or बहात्तर \or त्र्याहत्तर \or चौऱ्याहत्तर \or
  पंच्याहत्तर \or शहात्तर \or सत्याहत्तर \or अठ्याहत्तर \or एकोणऐशी \or ऐंशी
  \or एक्याऐंशी \or ब्याऐंशी \or त्र्याऐंशी \or चौऱ्याऐंशी \or पंच्याऐंशी \or
  शह्यांशी \or सत्यांऐंशी \or अठ्ठ्याऐंशी \or एकोणनव्वद \or नव्वद \or एक्याण्णव
  \or ब्याण्णव \or त्र्याण्णव \or चौऱ्याण्णव \or पंच्याण्णव \or शहाण्णव \or
  सत्याण्णव \or अठ्याण्णव \or नव्याण्णव \or शंभर\fi
}
\newcommand{\marathiwords}[1]{\expandafter\@marathiwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter}{\pagenumbering{roman}}{\pagenumbering{marathiwords}}{}{}
\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\patchcmd{\@memfront}{\pagenumbering{roman}}{\pagenumbering{marathiwords}}{}{}}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\testtext{%
वसईची लढाई मराठा साम्राज्य आणि पोर्तुगीज वसाहतकारांच्यात इ.स. १७३९ साली लढली गेलेली लढाई होती. यात मराठ्यांचे नेतृत्त्व थोरले बाजीराव पेशवे यांचा भाऊ चिमाजी अप्पा याने केले. यात मराठ्यांनी पोर्तुगीज वसाहतकारांवर विजय मिळवला.

शंकराजीपंत फडके या सरदाराने चिमाजी अप्पाला कळवले, की वसईतील पोर्तुगीजांवर चाल करायची असेल या मोहिमेच्या सुरुवातीलाच मराठ्यांनी अर्नाळा किल्ला काबीज करणे गरजेचे होते. शंकराजीने स्थानिक लोकांशी मसलत करून अर्नाळा घेण्यासाठी त्यांची मदत मागितली. गोविंदजी कासार आणि गवराजी पाटील या बोलिंज गावाच्या रहिवाशांसह गंगाजी नाईक अंजूरकर, बाजीराव बेलोसे आणि रायाजीराव सुर्वे हे मराठा सरदार ४०० सैनिकांचे पथक घेऊन खुश्कीच्या मार्गाने निघाले, तर दर्यासारंग मानाजी आंग्रे याने गुराबा घेऊन समुद्रावरून अर्नाळ्यावर चाल केली.

मार्च २८, इ.स. १७३७ रोजी मराठा सैन्याने अर्नाळ्यात गाफील असलेल्या पोर्तुगीजांवर हल्ला केला आणि त्यांना हुसकावून लावून किल्ला काबीज केला. या विजयाची स्मृती म्हणून किल्ल्याच्या उत्तरेकडच्या तटबंदीमध्ये एक शिलालेख कोरण्यात आला; जो अजूनही शाबूत आहे. शंकराजीपंताने लगेचच किल्ल्याची डागडुजी सुरू केली व किल्ला पुन्हा भांडता केला. जानेवारी इ.स. १७३८पर्यंत तीन बुरूज बांधून तयार झाले. त्यांना भैरव बुरूज, भवानी बुरूज आणि बावा बुरूज अशी नावे देण्यात आली. मार्च महिन्यात किल्ला पूर्ण लढता झाल्यावर मराठा सैन्य आसपासच्या प्रदेशात पसरले व वर्सोवा तसेच धारावी या बेटांवर त्यांनी आपले बस्तान बसवले.

फेब्रुवारी १७, इ.स. १७३९ रोजी मराठ्यांनी चिमाजी अप्पाच्या नेतृत्त्वाखाली खुद्द वसईवर चाल केली. चालून येत असलेली फौज पाहून पोर्तुगीजांनी आपली शिबंदी वसईच्या किल्ल्यात घेतली व वसईचा वेढा सुरू झाला. मराठ्यांनी शिताफीने पूर्ण किल्ल्याभोवती घेरा घातला व किल्ल्याची पूर्ण नाकेबंदी करून टाकली. अत्यंत चिकाटीने चालवलेल्या वेढ्यासोबतच त्यांनी किल्ल्यावर गनिमी काव्याने हल्ले चालू ठेवले. अशाच एका हल्ल्यात पोर्तुगीजांचा सेनापती सिल्व्हेरा दि मेंझेस मृत्युमुखी पडला. तरीही पोर्तुगीजांनी हिमतीने लढा चालू ठेवला आणि चालून येणाऱ्या मराठ्यांच्या लाटांचा हातबाँब, बंदुका आणि उखळी तोफा वापरून प्रतिकार चालू ठेवला. आपल्या वरचढ तंत्रज्ञान, अस्त्रे व शस्त्रांनी पोर्तुगीजांनी मराठ्यांचे बरेच नुकसान केले; परंतु मराठ्यांनी आपला वेढा सैल होऊ दिला नाही. इकडे आंग्र्यांच्या आरमाराने समुद्री मार्गही बंद केलेले होते आणि तेथूनही रसद मिळणे बंद केले होते.

शेवटी मे १६, इ.स. १७३९ रोजी वेढा धसास लागला आणि मराठ्यांनी किल्ल्यावर एल्गार केला. चिमाजी अप्पाने स्वतः पहिली तोफ डागली आणि नारो शंकर दाणी याच्या नेतृत्वाखालील घोडदळ आणि आंग्र्यांचे आरमार दोहो बाजूंनी पोर्तुगीजांवर तुटून पडले. तोफखान्याच्या सरदार गिरमाजी कानिटकराने किल्ला पुरता भाजून काढला आणि मानाजी आंग्र्याच्या बरकंदाजांनी गुराबांवरुन पोर्तुगीज शिपाई टिपून काढणे सुरू ठेवले. या भडिमारापुढे पोर्तुगीज बचावाने नांगी टाकली आणि त्यांनी मराठ्यांकडे शरणागती मागितली. शरण आले असताही आपल्या सैन्यास मानानिशी वाट काढून द्यावी आणि त्यांना अभय द्यावे, अशी विनंती त्यांनी चिमाजी अप्पाकडे केली. मराठ्यांनी ही विनंती मंजूर केली आणि शरण आलेल्या सैन्याला त्यांनी वाट करून दिली.
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{मुखपृष्ठ}

\testtext\testtext\testtext\testtext\testtext
\testtext\testtext\testtext\testtext\testtext
\testtext\testtext\testtext\testtext\testtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @egre! I tried this and it works perfectly when I use it in a file. However, when kept in the preamble, just above \makeatother, the title-page is not numbered (as expected) but then the numbering starts from three (तीन)!
If you want, I can post a MWE as a reply. I have not learned TeX, so I am unable to figure out what is happening.
Do you think that you can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RohitD.Holkar Probably it’s better to ask a new question with the minimal example