# Mapping Devanagari numerals with LuaLaTeX

Tags: numbering, luatex, indic, marathi

I have released a package named [`marathi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/marathi) which aims for typing Marathi language with great efficiency. This package requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. XeLaTeX with package `fontspec` provides a way to map arabic numerals with Devanagari ones. Try the following code -

```
% !TEX TS-Program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
\section{एक}
\section{दोन}
\end{document}
```

This gives correct mapping of Devanagari numerals. Unfortunately this function is not available with `LuaLaTeX`. Try the following code.

```
% !TEX TS-Program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
\section{एक}
\section{दोन}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following warning -

```
Input mapping not supported in LuaTeX.
```

Why is it not possible in LuaLaTeX is my first question.

I have tried to generate Devanagari numerals with LuaLaTeX using a solution given in [this](http://%5Cmakeatletter%20%5Cdef%5C@arabic#1%7B%5Cexpandafter%5Cdevanagaridigits%5Cexpandafter%7B%5Cnumber#1%7D%7D%20%5Cmakeatother) answer. It works almost fine unless a package using definition `\@arabic` is used. Try this code (you need to install package `marathi` and as per the package requirement Shobhika font which is mostly included in the TeX-distribution) -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marathi}

\begin{document}
\section{एक}
\section{दोन}
\end{document}
```

This shall produce good results with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but I got an error with package when I used a package which treats `\@arabic` differently. There might be many such packages. The answer which I have referred also warns us about its effects, though I would like to use a softer way which will not produce un-predicted errors but will give me Devanagari numerals where necessary. Is there any way to make the package ignore the redefinition of `\@arabic` when it is already used by a package, but mapping the numerals when there is no such package loaded. Concerned definitions can be found on line no. 66 and 67 of the package.

---

Package `babel` does not give local enumeration. Try this code.

```
\tracinglostchars = 2 % Print a warning message if a character is missing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % To format the MWE for TeX.SX
\usepackage[english, bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.counters]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import, main, mapdigits]{marathi}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0,Ligatures={Common,Discretionary},Numbers=OldStyle]{Shobhika}
\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures={Common, Discretionary}]{Shobhika}
\babelfont[marathi]{rm}{Shobhika}
\babelfont[marathi]{sf}{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item अबक
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item अबक
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item अबक
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You’ve edited a new question into your answer (which more people are likely to notice if you post a new one than if you put it at the end of a question that already has an accepted answer). [I believe the answer to it is here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/numbering-enumerate-environments-and-pages-with-devanagari-alphabet)

Comment: Thanks @Davislor! This is exactly how `polyglossia` renews the enumeration counters in `gloss-marathi.ldf`. `babel-mr.ini` is lacking these definitions. I have asked this question [here](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/74#issuecomment-640408753) on the GitHub repo.

Comment: There is an alphabetic counter for Hindi in `babel` (which you can use with `\babelprovide[import, maparabic, alph=alphabetic]{hindi}`), but it is not defined for Marathi. You can, however, create it yourself with `enumitem`.

Comment: I wish that the process becomes easier on the users' side. I will see `babel-hin.ini` and if the counters are good enough for the requirements of Marathi, I'll open up a new pull request. I personally manage to get everything right in my documents. I opened this question to ease the process for other new Marathi users with the help of [my package](https://ctan.org/pkg/marathi). I want to give my users the best that LaTeX has.

Comment: I’m glad that someone is motivated to improve support for the language. I hope I was able to help in some way, but I don’t speak Marathi and would be completely unqualified to do the work myself.

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: One other minor thing. If you’re using SHobhika, you can simplify the font commands to `\babelfont{rm}[Scale = 1.0]{Shobhika}`. Even the `Scale=` parameter is a very minor tweak that only matters if you’re scaling every other font you use to the height of the main font. This font doesn’t have any of the OpenType features I used for Libertinus in my example, it’s not sans-serif, and it supports both scripts I wanted to use. A `\babelfont` will automatically be called with the currently-selected language and its associated script. So you don’t need to copy all that code. :)

Comment: Yes. That is much easier. Also one more very important font-feature. Kindly add `Renderer=Harfbuzz` to the `\defaultfontfeatures` command. It is very much needed to get Devanagari ligatures right.

Comment: I updated the MWE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `babel` package, running on LuaHBTeX (that is, LuaLaTeX from 2020 or later), supports this through the `mapdigits` feature.  This example will change the digits to Devanagari in page numbers, chapter numbers, the table of contents, etc., and in Marathi text, but not in English text or math mode.

```
%% This MWE requires LuaHBTeX 1.12.0 or later.
\tracinglostchars = 2 % Print a warning message if a character is missing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % To format the MWE for TeX.SX
\usepackage[english, bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.counters]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import, main, mapdigits]{marathi}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer = HarfBuzz}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale = 1.0]{Shobhika}

\newcommand\textenglish[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
\newenvironment{english}{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}{\end{otherlanguage}}

\begin{document}
\section{एक}
\textenglish{The number 42 in English. In math mode:} \(42\). 

\section{दोन}
\textenglish{In Marathi:} 42.
\textenglish{This is Section} \arabic{section}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Shobhika font sample]

If you are compiling with Babel and XeLaTeX, the `sectioning=` package option will work for counters such as page and chapter numbers, and you can pass `maparabic` instead of `mapdigits` to `\babelprovide` to make `\arabic` counters such as numbered lists use different numerals.  It also provides the command `\marathidigits{42}`.  Or you can just type in Marathi in your editor the way you normally do.

If the localized strings are unsatisfactory, you can override them by redefining `\marathicontentsname`, `\marathichaptername`, `\marathiabstractname`, etc.

The `polyglossia` package provides a similar command to map digits, `\devanagaridigits`.

Comment: Please see [this](https://pastebin.com/0MMgHk0G) log file. I saved your MWE with test.tex name and compiled it with luahbtex (v1.12.0).

Comment: @Niranjan you should use lualatex to compile the example not luahbtex (which will use plain format).

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer . Now it gives good output. This answer definitely gives a good solution with babel, but now I as I experimented more with it I realized that translations for polyglossia are much more updated and maintained. I'll look into `babel-mr.ini` now, but isn't there any good solution with polyglossia as of now?

Comment: @Niranjan babel is well maintained and updated frequently. If you find errors in the ini open an issue or a pull request at the github.

Comment: I didn't say babel is not maintained. The translations are not updated. They are old and needs to be updated. I am opening a pull request for the same :)

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, I saw it. But you should create a real pull request by clicking on the "open pull request" button. Then Javier can simply merge.

Comment: Oops! I just changed the file. Forgot to create the pull request. [Now done here](https://github.com/latex3/babel/pull/75).

Comment: @Niranjan I see how my wording was confusing about which command to use. I’ve made a small edit.

Comment: @Niranjan Thanks! Both `babel` and `polyglossia` could use some attention from native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I used my first answer to provide a solution that works with the toolchain as it exists today.  But I’ll also try to answer the several questions you literally asked.

Only XeTeX supports the `Mapping=` feature of `fontspec`.  If you have one solution that works in XeLaTeX and another solution that works in LuaLaTeX, you can use the macros in the `iftex` package to select the right one at compile time.

If there’s some other package that redefines `\@arabic` in a way that conflicts with yours, you have a few options. You can make your definition come last by wrapping it in `\AtEndPreamble` or `\AtBeginDocument`. You can document that your package must be loaded in a particular order. You can detect the other package with `\@ifpackageloaded` (possibly deferred until `\AtEndPreamble` so that it works whether you load your package first or last) and attempt to monkey-patch it.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. My package already uses `iftex` for conditionally using `Mapping=` function. Is there any way to decide the compiler if a certain package is loaded?

Comment: I am thinking of using babel `ifluatex` and polyglossia `ifxetex` :)

Comment: Also it would be great if you can explain the use of the parameters used in your MWE.

Comment: @Niranjan `\@ifpackageloaded`. You can also check for options the other package was loaded with.

Comment: @Niranjan Which parameters did you have in mind?

Comment: `\usepackage[english,layout=sectioning.counters]{babel}`, `\babelprovide[import, main]`, `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}`, `Ligatures={Common,Discretionary},Numbers=OldStyle`

Comment: What is the equivalent of `setdefaultlanguage` in babel?

Comment: babel doesn't seem to give local enumeration. See the code in my question.

Comment: @Niranjan The equivalent of `\setdefaultlanguage` is the `main` option to `\babelprovide`.

Comment: @Niranjan If you want more information on the details of options to `babel`, I do give brief descriptions, but I would recommend searching for them in [the manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf)

Comment: Okay sure. I will do that :)