# How to write श्र ज्ञ ऋ ् ॆऽ in latex

Tags: fonts, indic

```
\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}

{\dn  shree, gya,.r}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have some input method that can enter Devanagari into your source file, you should use Unicode.  My own preference is `babel` in LuaLaTeX.  (Here is [one of several examples.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548203/61644))  You can use either `babel` or `polyglossia` in either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and they will support any Devanagari font you could use in your word processor.

If you want to use Latin-script transliteration in your source file, you can use the [`xetex devanagari` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetex-devanagari) to load an input mapping for that.  There is also a `devanagari` package that you can fall back to, if some publisher is still forcing you to write South Asian languages with 8-bit font encodings in the 2020s. [Here is an example.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408326/using-devanagri-package-in-latex/408336#408336)

Comment: It's working in my system. Can you tell me the transliteration for the code used here. 
 {\dn m\?r\? mAtA aOr EptA ko smEp\0t h\4.}

Comment: @VyomShastriz The syntax of `\dn` is documented [on page 8 of the manual, here.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/devanagari/velthuis/doc/manual.pdf) I’m not sure what some of the macros in that sample are doing, so you might want to check how they are defined in your preamble.

Answer (score 2):

You could download the `Noto Serif Devanagari` and `Noto Sans Devanagari` fonts (if you haven't already done so) from [Google](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) and compile the following test document under either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. (Please note that I copied and pasted the string `श्र ज्ञ ऋ ् ॆऽ`  straight from the title of the OP's posting.) Note that the option `Script=Devanagari` is needed by both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX; additionally, `Renderer=Harfbuzz` is needed by LuaLaTeX. (Many thanks, @davislor, for providing this suggestion!)

[image]

Of course, if you prefer, you may use any other OpenType font that provides the required glyphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,iftex}

\ifxetex
  \setmainfont{Noto Serif Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]
  \setsansfont{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]
\else % LuaTeX
  \setmainfont{Noto Serif Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Harfbuzz]
  \setsansfont{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Harfbuzz]
\fi

\begin{document}
श्र ज्ञ ऋ ् ॆऽ

\medskip
\sffamily
श्र ज्ञ ऋ ् ॆऽ
\end{document}
```

Comment: The output is actually wrong in the above screenshot, though adding `[Script=Devanagari]` after `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` should fix it I think.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - Many thanks for drawing attention to this problem. In the case at hand, adding the option [Script=Devanagari] doesn't help under LuaLaTeX, but it makes a huge difference under XeLaTeX. Again, many thanks for your comment and suggestion.

Comment: Using devanagari I able to write all the  alphabet except श्र ऋ, ्, ए, ऐ, ञ, त्न द्द, द्ध. I believe that all devanagari letters are there. What are key to write these letters can any one tell me???

Comment: In LuaLaTeX, you want to load the Devanagari font with `[Script=Devanagari, Renderer=HarfBuzz]`.

Comment: @Davislor - Many thanks for this suggestion; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I checked it's not working. Even I searched for the package devanagari but the transliteration specified there was not working in my system.

Comment: @VyomShastri - Sorry, but where in my answer did I mention a *package* called devanagari?

Answer (score 0):

{\dn \380w \3E2w  \31Bw   \35Ew \303w \35Fw }

P.S.

you can check out the table \30Xw ~ \3FFw like below...
30{\dn  \300w  \301w  \302w  \303w  \304w  \305w  \306w  \307w  \308w  \309w  \30Aw  \30Bw \30Cw \30Dw \30Ew  \30Fw }\\

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!