# Fontspec mapping tex-text AND devanagarinumerals

Tags: xetex, fontspec, punctuation, devanagari

I am unable to figure out the correct way to tell `fontspec` to adhere to both `Mapping=tex-text` and `Mapping=devanagarinumerals`. Here's an MWE:

```
% !TeX program = XeLateX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping={devanagarinumerals,tex-text},AutoFakeBold=2.0]{Siddhanta}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping={tex-text},AutoFakeBold=2.0]{Siddhanta}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping={devanagarinumerals},AutoFakeBold=2.0]{Siddhanta}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item क---ख
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The desired output is:
१. क—ख

and not

1. क—ख (`Mapping={tex-text}`)

or
१. क---ख (`Mapping={devanagarinumerals}`)

I presume this is super simple, but nothing I have tried works, including `Mapping={devanagarinumerals,tex-text}` or adding `\defaultfontfeatures{mapping=tex-text}`. Any help/insights would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It is not super simple. Xetex can use only one mapping, that means you must create a new mapping which combines both.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would it be easier to make - active and just create the em and en dashes programmatically? Which approach would you recommend?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I would use lualatex, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548203/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks