# Page numbering with Tengwar font

Tags: fonts, page-numbering

Using the type system developed by JRR Tolkien with TeX and its extensions is tricky but possible. One solution is the package `tengwarscript`. Now the interesting thing about the writing system is that the corresponding number system is not base 10, but base 12.

I wonder if anyone has ever tried to automatically convert the number of pages into the corresponding characters. Unfortunately, my current knowledge about TeX is not sufficient to implement something like that. Can someone help me?

Comment: The basic technique can be found here: [Numbering enumerate environments and pages with Devanagari alphabet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366321/2693). This is effectively a duplicate, but if you have trouble using it to do what you want, edit your question with a sample document showing what you tried and we can help you with that.

Comment: My problem is not changing the font of the number, but changing the number system. I have absolutely no clue about changing the number system from base 10 to base 12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not completely sure, but as far as I understand it, Tengwar not only uses a number system with base of 12, but it also places the least significant digit to the left.

The following code creates a user macro `\tengwarnumeral` that converts a number to its Tengwar counterpart. It does so by first converting the number to a sequence that represents the single digits of the Tengwar number (where the order of digits is already flipped) and then replacing the strings in this sequence by the correct glyph using the `tengwarscript` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}
\usepackage[annatar]{tengwarscript}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int
\int_new:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int
\seq_new:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq

\NewDocumentCommand { \tengwarnumeral } { m } { 
    \seq_clear:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq
    \int_set:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { #1 }
    \int_do_until:nn { \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int <= 0 } {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int { \int_mod:nn { \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int } { 12 } }
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int = { 0 } {
            \int_sub:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { 12 } 
        } {
            \int_sub:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int } 
        }
        \int_set:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { \int_div_truncate:nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { 12 } }
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq { \int_use:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int } 
    }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq {
        \str_case:nn { ##1 } {
            { 0 } { \Tzero }
            { 1 } { \Tone }
            { 2 } { \Ttwo }
            { 3 } { \Tthree }
            { 4 } { \Tfour }
            { 5 } { \Tfive }
            { 6 } { \Tsix }
            { 7 } { \Tseven }
            { 8 } { \Teight }
            { 9 } { \Tnine }
            { 10 } { \Tten }
            { 11 } { \Televen }
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tengwarnumeral{3}

% is 12 + 3, so should be: 3 1
\tengwarnumeral{15}

% is 1728 + 144 + 120 + 3, so should be: 3 10 1 1
\tengwarnumeral{1995}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to use Unicode-flavoured fonts with `fontspec`, such as Tengwar Telcontar, you can adjust the second part of the macro where the conversion takes place as follows (I also added the Unicode codepoints that the Tengwar numerals would be assigned to if the [latest encoding proposal](http://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC2/WG2/docs/n1641/n1641.htm) would be accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\tengwarfont{tengtelc.ttf}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int
\int_new:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int
\seq_new:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq

\NewDocumentCommand { \tengwarnumeral } { m } { 
    \seq_clear:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq
    \int_set:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { #1 }
    \int_do_until:nn { \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int <= 0 } {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int { \int_mod:nn { \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int } { 12 } }
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int = { 0 } {
            \int_sub:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { 12 } 
        } {
            \int_sub:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int } 
        }
        \int_set:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { \int_div_truncate:nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tempa_int { 12 } }
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq { \int_use:N \l_tengwarnumeral_tempb_int } 
    }
    \group_begin:
    \tengwarfont
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tengwarnumeral_tengwardigits_seq {
        \str_case:nn { ##1 } {
            { 0 } { \char"E070 } % \char"160B0
            { 1 } { \char"E071 } % \char"160B3
            { 2 } { \char"E072 } % \char"160E2
            { 3 } { \char"E073 } % \char"160E3
            { 4 } { \char"E074 } % \char"160E4
            { 5 } { \char"E075 } % \char"160E5
            { 6 } { \char"E076 } % \char"160E6
            { 7 } { \char"E077 } % \char"160E7
            { 8 } { \char"E078 } % \char"160E8
            { 9 } { \char"E079 } % \char"160E9
            { 10 } { \char"E07A } % \char"160EA
            { 11 } { \char"E07B } % \char"160EB
        }
    }
    \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tengwarnumeral{3}

% is 12 + 3, so should be: 3 1
\tengwarnumeral{15}

% is 1728 + 144 + 120 + 3, so should be: 3 10 1 1
\tengwarnumeral{1995}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! With ```\let\oldthepage\thepage``` and ```\renewcommand*\thepage{\tengwarnumeral{\oldthepage}}``` I was able to change the font of the page numbering.

Comment: @Titanlord Yes, sorry for not really addressing page numbering in my answer ... I thought that the real problem is how to convert these numbers ... =D