# How can I change the chapter numbers in Bengali numerals/words

Tags: xetex, chapters, polyglossia, indic

How can I change the chapter numbers in Bengali numerals/words. The chapter numbers are coming in Arabic format by default, instead of specifying numeral in font option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals = Bengali, changecounternumbering=true]    {bengali}
\setmainfont{Bangla Akademi}


\begin{document}

\chapter{ভূমিকা}

\end{document}
```

The above code give the following result

[image]

I expect an output like this

**অধ্যায় ১**

**অধ্যায় ২**
...

or like this

প্রথম অধ্যায় (=First Chapter)

দ্বিতীয় অধ্যায় (=Second Chapter)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246881/how-to-get-section-numbers-and-page-numbers-with-bengali-numerals-in-latex-or-xe)

Comment: Try package `latexbangla` on CTAN. The polyglossia package's support for Bengali is still poor/incomplete, and I remember [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300070/adding-full-non-english-unicode-language-bengali-support-to-polyglossia) on this site asking about how to contribute improvements and the maintainer of polyglossia wasn't responsive.

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician, the following line solved the problem           `\renewcommand\thechapter{\bengalinumeral{chapter}}`. However, It would be more "natural"  if I get the output like "প্রথম অধ্যায়"