# Bengali numerals in LaTeX

Tags: languages

I am having difficulties in having Benagli numerals in latex.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage[numerals=Bengali]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\newfontfamily\bengalifont{SolaimanLipi}






\begin{document}

\section{test}
Test - {\bengalifont পরীক্ষা} - test.
\bengalifont
\bengalidigits
আমাদের স্কুলের যত ছাত্র তাহার মধ্যে এমন কেহই ছিল না, যে পাগলা দাশুকে
না চিনে। যে লোক আর কাহাকেও জানে না, সেও সকলের আগে পাগলা দাশুকে চিনিয়া
লয়। সেবার একজন নূতন দারোয়ান আসিল, একেবারে আনকোরা পাড়াগেঁয়ে লোক, কিন্তু
প্রথম যখন সে পাগলা দাশুর নাম শুনিল, তখনই সে আন্দাজে ঠিক ধরিয়া লইল যে,
এই ব্যক্তিই পাগলা দাশু। কারণ তার মুখের চেহারায়, কথাবার্তায়, চলনে চালনে
বোঝা যাইত যে তাহার মাথায় একটু 'ছিট' আছে। তাহার চোখদুটি গোল-গোল,
কানদুটা অনাবশ্যক রকমের বড়, মাথায় এক বস্তা ঝাঁকড়া চুল। চেহারাটা দেখিলেই
মনে হয়--- 1 2 3 34 

\vskip 10mm

% Specific font can be used for any part of the document
{বিঃদ্রঃ এই বাংলা পাতাটি লেখার জন্য XeTeX ব্যবহার করা হয়েছে।}

\end{document}
```

How to have Bengali numerals ?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and compiling the file using xelatex.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the similar http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70903/124577

Comment: Just a bit curious, have you found a solution?